# Nginx container fails to start on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm attempting to serve simple static page with Nginx on Cloud Run. But the container fails to properly start serving.

Container is starting, as shown by the debug lines echoed from `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
2019-05-26T22:19:02.340289Z testing config
2019-05-26T22:19:02.433935Z nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2019-05-26T22:19:02.434903Z nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
2019-05-26T22:19:02.436605Z starting on 8080
2019-05-26T22:19:02.487188Z2019/05/26 22:19:02 [alert] 6#6: prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) failed (22: Invalid argument)
```

and eventually terminates

```
2019-05-26T22:20:00.153060259ZContainer terminated by the container manager on signal 9.
```

In order to conform with the [Cloud Run service contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract) specifically listening on `$PORT` the `docker-entrypoint.sh` performs [$PORT substitution in `conf.d/*.conf`](https://serverfault.com/a/919212).

```
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine

COPY nginx-default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I'm pretty confident issue lies within `docker-entrypoint.sh` because once $PORT is hardcoded as `8080` and image looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine

COPY nginx-default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Cloud Run "runs" fine.

The code performing the substitution:

```sh
export NGINX_PORT=${PORT:-8080}
for f in $(find /etc/nginx/conf.d/ -type f -name '*.conf'); do
  envsubst '$NGINX_PORT' < $f > $f
done
```

*NOTE*: reading `< $f` and writing `> $f` to the same file works as tested by running the container locally.

Expected

- nginx configuration gets `$PORT` placeholder substituted with actual values
- container runs and listens on `$PORT` on Cloud Run

Actual

- container fails to run on Cloud Run
- container runs and listens on `$PORT` locally

Comment: Does your script (/docker-entrypoint.sh) begin with a shebang similar to #!/bin/bash?

Comment: In your code your question you have COPY nginx-default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template    .... did you perhaps mean   ... is that the correct destination for the configuration file?  How does that become a real configuration file for nginx?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Do not do this `NOTE: reading < $f and writing > $f`

Comment: Instead, do an in-place edit of your file like this: `sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' filename`. This is an example and is not written for your config file.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for suggestion, ended up replacing `envsubst` with `sed`. The mystery remains unsolved though, since locally things worked no problems.

Comment: @Kolban yes, that's a copy-pasta but i had it fixed locally.

Comment: And what results from the config files after substitution? Is $PORT actually being inserted?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, for exact snippet see the updated post on the top.

Comment: Are you saying the problem is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by replacing

```
for f in $(find /etc/nginx/conf.d/ -type f -name '*.conf'); do
  envsubst '$NGINX_PORT' < $f > $f
done
```

with

```
sed -i "s/\${NGINX_PORT}/${NGINX_PORT}/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
```

and changing `$NGINX_PORT` -> `${NGINX_PORT}` in `*.conf` files to avoid substitution ambiguities

Comment: Can you add to your answer a before and after example of the line being changed? Double check your `sed` line. You are replacing with the exact same item. Typo?

Comment: not typo: 

0. assuming env var `NGINX_PORT` is set to `8080`
1. the `s`ubstitution is inside double quotes `"` which gets interpreted by the shell first, becoming `s/${NGINX_PORT}/8080/g`
2. notice '\$' which escapes the sign preventing the substitution of the pattern to match

Comment: Where are my glasses? I missed the escape character.

Answer (score 5):

I have published a blog post to show how to run nginx in a Cloud Run container (alongside with a process).

You can read the article here: https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multiple-processes-easy-way/ or take a look at the code repository at https://github.com/ahmetb/multi-process-container-lazy-solution

Basically, the nginx.conf file should be something like:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080; # Cloud Run PORT env variable
        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout;

        # if you need to serve static access, specify an absolute path like below
        location /static/ {
            alias /src/static/;
        }

        # anything else is routed to your app that you would start on port 8081
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }
    }
}

daemon off;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

You can sort of safely hard code port 8080 in your `nginx.conf` as it's very unlikely to change in the foreseeable future on Cloud Run.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I have wasted a lot of time on this issue without knowing that the applications on Cloud Run could be only run on the port 8080.

Comment: You can actually now specify custom port numbers in Cloud Run. No need to change the nginx.conf just for thr port number.

Comment: I tried that actually, but the container health check keeps on failing until I hardcoded the port as 8080 in my application and I've added the same port as the custom port in Cloud Run. Not sure if I missed anything there.