# Cloud Run error: Container failed to start

Tags: dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I am failing to get a basic Angular app deploying to Google Cloud Run. The error would suggest it is not being served correctly at port 8080, but running locally on my machine localhost:8080 displays the app. So possibly I need something extra for cloud run, if anybody has some idea?

The details are as follows:

I create a basic angular app

```
ng new test-app
```

The Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

ENV PORT=8080

FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=node /app/dist/test-app /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Locally I run the built container and I can see it at localhost:8080

```
docker container run -p 8080:80 gcr.io/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/test-app:$IMAGE
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUEc4.png)

I then deploy to Google Cloud Run managed.

```
gcloud run deploy test-app --image gcr.io/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/test-app:$IMAGE --platform managed
```

However, it fails to start with the error

```
Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

There are no other errors in the logs.

Thanks.

The solution which worked I took from [How to change the port of nginx when using with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364019/how-to-change-the-port-of-nginx-when-using-with-docker)

I created the nginx.conf file, setting the port to 8080 & server to 0.0.0.0

```
# on alpine, copy to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user                            root;
worker_processes                auto;

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                    off;
    access_log                  off;
    keepalive_timeout           3000;
    server {
        listen                  8080;
        root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index                   index.html;
        server_name             0.0.0.0;
        client_max_body_size    16m;
    }
}
```

And updated the Dockerfile to copy over this file.

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

ENV PORT=8080

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/streamin-app/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: You might want to study the following ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318026/nginx-container-fails-to-start-on-cloud-run ... my understanding is that you can't listen on port 8080 ... but rather you must listen on whatever is in the PORT environment variable ... the referenced Q/A shows how to modify nginx before start to use the correct port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think is related to container listening on all network interfaces.

According to the official documentation:

> A common reason for Cloud Run services failing to start is that the
>   server process inside the container is configured to listen on the
>   localhost (127.0.0.1) address. This refers to the loopback network
>   interface, which is not accessible from outside the container and
>   therefore Cloud Run health check cannot be performed, causing the
>   service deployment failure.
>
> To solve this, configure your application to start the HTTP server to
>   listen on all network interfaces, commonly denoted as 0.0.0.0.

Comment: where's the actual solution?  what code did you have to write for this, what script update?

Comment: Thanks this is what worked for me. I am using FastAPI python and adding --host 0.0.0.0 resolved my issue.

Comment: After a day of terrible suffering this was it! Can't believe Google docs make no mention of it and logs are so cryptic as the server still starts. For Fastify users - `fastify.listen(port, '0.0.0.0')`

Answer (score 3):

1. BTW I didn't mess with nginx at all
2. I just have EXPOSE 4200 in my docker file
3. I added the container port of 4200 to the settings for the container here:

[image]

It then gave me a URL up on top:

[image]

This gave me an invalid host header error which I fixed by redeploying my container with:

```
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

See discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677629/invalid-host-header-when-running-angular-cli-development-server-c9-io).

Answer (score 1):

“docker container run -p 8080:80 gcr.io/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/test-app:$IMAGE”

shows you mapped port 8080 of your local machine to port 80 for your image, which indicates that your image is listening on port 80.

You can either 1) change your image or 2) deploy to cloud run with custom port:

gcloud alpha run deploy ... -port 80