# Cloud Run: "Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable." When I use 8080

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, nuxt.js, google-cloud-run

I got [this error message](https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/issues/1) when I try to run my container in Google Cloud Run.

```
type: Ready
status: 'False'
reason: HealthCheckContainerError
message: |-
Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

I already checked the followings but nothing helped to me:

- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting
- [Cloud Run error: Container failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524020/cloud-run-error-container-failed-to-start)

My container is running locally and it's listening on default PORT `8080` with HOST configured as `0.0.0.0`.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD npm start
```

Any idea on why Cloud Run keeps failing to listen on the port?

---

Project GitHub repo:

https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app

Comment: Edit your question with all details. Links change, break and get deleted. The content of links might change in the future. It is OK to include links as an addition reference but you must include everything in the question.

Comment: What's your logs in Cloud Logging?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere see my first comment here: https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/issues/1

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this problem? I'm facing the same problem and would appreciate any help!

Comment: I faced the same problem and I haven't found a solution yet. I'm facing this problem when I try to convert my image file that contains a static web project based on Nginx to service. Did you find a solution???

Comment: See the answer from @Bk Lim. that was the solution for me.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Just to check, are you using the M1 Macbook? I found a solution for myself after facing this issue for some time, might not be the solution for you but just to share some insights I found for other MacBook users.

tl;dr

> build your Docker container with the `--platform linux/amd64` flag before deploying the image to Cloud Run

========================================================

Long story:

Aside from the `container failed to start and listen to the $PORT` error, my logs were showing the following: `Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /usr/local/bin/npm: exec format error`. Upon some digging, one of the reasons this happens is that we are trying to run an arm64 image (built on M1 MacBook) on a different host platform.

GCP does mention on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract) here that `Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit. Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format.`

I guess that explains why building the image on Cloud Build works from the other answer in this post.

Comment: This worked for me.  The full command: `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t image-name:v0.1.0 .`  Reference: [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/)

Comment: After losing more hours of my life to this than I care to admit to, this solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on M1 as well. By the way, you should update your reference to "the other answer in this post".

Comment: This worked for me. I love stackoverflow. Thank you very much. Congrats to everyone that got new laptops recently.

Comment: `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t TAG_NAME .`

Comment: Even Google Cloud could not resolve my issue until I came to SO. M1 and its issue. Definitely `--platform=linux/amd64`

Comment: This caused immense frustraition, glad there is a quick resolution but they should just always specify that argument if this edge case can come up imo

Comment: The one answer chatgpt couldn't solve for me. Kudos, my man.

Comment: I cannot stress how helpul this answer was! many many thanks

Comment: Thank you SO much! Please let me know if I can buy you a coffee/beer!!

Answer (score 0):

The attached logs seem to indicate your entrypoint may be malformed.

> Failed to create init process: failed to load /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error",

Are there any commands or arguments specified as input? Would it be possible for you to put the complete yaml for the cloud run instance either in your repo, a gist, or in this question?

[image: Cloud Console]

Comment: You can found my YAML file here: 
https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/issues/1

Comment: I noticed you are browsing to 'localhost:8080' locally. If you browse to '0.0.0.0:8080' does that work? Localhost may be binding to '127.0.0.1:8080'.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#listen_address

Comment: Yes, '0.0.0.0:8080' is also working locally.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in Dockerfile for node:10 official image https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/4ab6ab7d06845aa950054ec5522fe8b81927bf05/10/alpine3.10/Dockerfile they don't expose any port. As long as you are not changing anything to ENTRYPOINT I would suspect you add EXPOSE 8080 to your Dockerfile and it should do the work.

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD npm start
```

**UPDATE**

As the issue seems rather strange I went an extra mile and quickly set up copy of your repo with the build pipeline and everything work just fine.
Here you can access your app https://testssr-6dl3hr2riq-uc.a.run.app/

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD npm start
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c','docker build --no-cache -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/testssr:$SHORT_SHA .']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push','gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/testssr:$SHORT_SHA']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
    - 'beta'
    - 'run'
    - 'deploy'
    - 'testssr'
    - '--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/testssr:$SHORT_SHA'
    - '--region=us-central1'
    - '--platform=managed'
```

Comment: `EXPOSE` has no effect on a Cloud Run container. It is a comment only in Cloud Run.

Comment: @BalázsFodor-Pap does the update on this answer solve your issue? You can execute configs manually by following this doc https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/start-build-manually

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo No 'EXPOSE 8080' not solved my issue.
https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/blob/1b6108bf3f1b0333b81e326660a77ec37e01948a/Dockerfile#L8

Comment: If you look at my update I have removed the EXPOSE as it doesnt matter in cloud run. I have taken your repo and set up build pipeline, the only problem i faced was removing —only=production as It failed to build. After I have build your container it is running just fine on Cloud Run.

Comment: @MaciejPerliński and where should I update the cloudbuild.yaml file? I removed '--only=production' from my Dockerfile and it's still not workging. 

Is this cloudbuild.yaml mandatory? or the default: https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/issues/1#issue-804965635
is ok?

https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/pull/2

Comment: I have set up the Cloud Build and this cloud build is building your image whenever there is a change in your repository connected to the your project. So I'm not sure where is a problem but using Cloud Build for building the image and deploying it to the Cloud Run proves to be working fine and there is no problem with your code. To conclude cloudbuild.yaml is telling cloud build how to build and deploy your container.

Comment: By introducing Cloud Build you'll resolve your problem and introduce CD/CI tool which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You've only configured an environment variable on your Dockerfile but your program is not using it. [By default](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#edit-host-and-port), your app is still looking at **localhost:3000**.

To fix this, go to your **nuxt.config.js** and add the `server` config like this:

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  server: {
    port: process.env.PORT, // default: 3000
    host: process.env.HOST  // default: localhost
  },
  head: {
    title: 'ssr-app',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },

    ...
}
```

Afterwards, rebuild the container and redeploy a new revision to Cloud Run.

Comment: I edited nuxt.config.js as you suggested:
https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/blob/98716b099d74ff898832fe228fdd3fa52d92a334/nuxt.config.js#L3
It not solve the problem. I am just wondering, why my app run locally and why I able to open localhost:8080 (using 'docker run -d -p 8080:8080 imageid'), if its not working on Cloud Run ?

Comment: @BalázsFodor-Pap I agree. I'm wondering too as it seems to be working fine on Docker as well as on Cloud Run (both on master and the branch containing my solution) though I had to add '@nuxt/typescript-build' on dependencies to build the image. Are you sure that we have the code similar to what you're testing? I can see a Nuxt.js logo when access the Cloud Run URL.

Comment: Yes, I am almost 100% sure about that I'm using the same code, same image. (But maybe I miss something, because I'm new in these technologies)  


I put some screenshot to here: https://github.com/fodorpapbalazsdev/ssr-app/issues/1#issuecomment-776661398